# Error: The entity type ApplicationUser is not part of the model for the current context

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity-2

First of all I did previous investigation to ask help here.
I knowthere lots of similar questions but I have checked all of them. Nothing helps.

1. So I have created a new project in **VS 2015 ASP.NET MVC with 4.6.1 .NET Framework.**
2. I created a database with Identity tables based on http://identity.codeplex.com/
3. I created **EF model file** with all those tables and I verified that connection name is `DefaultConnection` within public `class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>` and `web.config`.

I expect that login will work by default but when I am triyng to login o register a new user I am facing this error.

> The entity type ApplicationUser is not part of the model for the
>   current context

Any clue?

P.S. In fact to do it takes about 10 minutes. Can anyone check it, please?

---

For someone who has the same problem I recommend this page 
http://danieleagle.com/blog/2014/05/setting-up-asp-net-identity-framework-2-0-with-database-first-vs2013-update-2-spa-template/

### By doing this you are able to get working all things.

*I resloved this problem like this.*

1. Create **ASP.NET MVC 4.5.6** project.
2. Create **empty database X** as you need.
3. Change **ConnectionString** in the created poject to this database X.
4. Start project and Register new users. It works fine! :)
   Notice if forget to change **ConnectionString** Visual Studio will create 
   default database under **APP_DATA**. I assue you dont wish it...
5. If you need to use **Entity Framework**, just crearte a separated Library Project and add **EDMX** and update it.
6. After this add **Reference to EF Library** in your **ASP.NET MVC Project** and add connection string from **EF Library project** to **web.config** of **ASP.NET MVC Project**.
7. After this find this

> public partial class YourEFLibraryProjectEntities: DbContext

and below change DefaultConnection to your YourEFLibraryProjectEntities

public YourEFLibraryProjectEntities()
            : base("name=YourEFLibraryProjectEntities")
        {
        }

8. Check all changes you are able to regisrter users/login.
   And also you can use **EF** like this for example

   public ActionResult Index()
   {
       try
       {
           YourEFLibraryProjectEntitiesctx = new YourEFLibraryProjectEntities();

   ```
       var users = ctx.AspNetUsers.ToList();
   }
   catch (Exception)
   {
   }
   return View();
   ```

   }

I hope it will helps!

Comment: The second answer there seems most appropriate to your scenario, even though it's not the accepted answer.

Comment: @ChrisPratt The second option doesnt work. But thank you anyway.